# Losing streaks in League of Legends

Tags: league-of-legends

It seems that when I'm in a losing streak, I play against way better opponents than when I'm in a winning streak.

Does the LoL matchmaking system take the previous games results into account? Or am I dreaming?

Edit: I've played a lot of other competitive games like Dota or online poker, and experienced losing streaks, but it's generally due to fatigue or bad luck. In League of Legends, it feels like something else.

Comment: The longer it takes to find a match, the more lenient the system is in who it puts together. Meaning instead of finding players with an MMR +-10 of each other it will increase that number until it can find a good match. You could also end up playing with or against "smurfs" who tend to play much than their MMR would suggest. There is a lot of variables that affect matchmaking so that at times it might seem like more luck is involved in hoping to get an even game.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill It might be true, but it doesn't really answer my question

Answer (score 5):

Riot Games didn't give the algorithm of their matchmaking system but they told their matchmaking system is based on elo/rating/mmr. If the waiting queue is long the teams will still be almost same rating but the players can change. In example:

Team A:
4 diamond
1 bronze

Team B:
5 plat

This case occurs usually in smaller servers but it may happen to you. Also when you're on a losing streak either you play bad yourself everyone else seems playing good or your teammates on their bad day and since the opponent is a bit fed they seem to look playing better.

Comment: Pretty much answers all scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

**Tilting is the main factor in loss streaks** in League of Legends. When I was going through Silver and Bronze I experienced this regularly. Becoming mad at the game and at your team has great negative effects on your gameplay, causing you to blame others for your own mistakes and also avoid the foundations of tactics to win, like warding, missing calls, and positioning.

The best way I've found to avoid tilting is to just take a break, although I no longer play League. I'm into the CS: GO MM and tilting is also very present in that game; I usually play Skyrim in between games and even take an hour break to do other things non computer related to avoid tilting.

Comment: The use of bold text, while it should be avoided to use other than the minimum, it was not incorrect.

Comment: It was, however, rather distracting, and doesn't really add anything of value, I'm afraid.  We try to make the content here as concise and readable as possible, and I don't think I would be the only one to find a specific word bolded throughout an answer distracting.

Comment: My answer to your previous comment backs up the fact i now understand the guidelines for this system, i will meet them, thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not about the MMR matchmaking but more about why you have winning or losing streaks.

In my experience, you will have winning streaks and losing streaks. The only thing is that when we win, we tend to tell ourselves that it's because we are good. When we lose, we subconsciously try to blame others or to minimize our part in it (you can always do something better).

But to be honest, sometimes you will win even without doing anything, being carried. Sometimes you will have to carry hard to win. It will depend.

I feel that at the end, the most important part is the sinergy with your team mates. So many times, I happened to win or crush a "good" composition with a "bad" composition just because everything goes well with your team mates, ganks have the perfect timing, people think about the same move beforehand and are synchronised etc...

Of course your skills, the level of your opponent is related to your victory rate, but you can't do much when there is no synergy in your team. You can just try to communicate more, without flaming. Try to do the best with what you have.

Comment: That's not the answer I'm looking for. I've played LoL and other games at a pretty high level (Plat I for LoL), but in this game, losing streaks AND winning streaks feel really "artificial"

Answer (score 0):

You are probably on tilt.

You lose games because you are still angry from the fact that you lost the last game. just take a 10-15minute break between each game not matter what the result was. this helped me a lot.

It seems like you play against much better players because they win... and you lose.

> Does the LoL matchmaking system take the previous games results into account?

Yes it does. you have a hidden [MMR](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Matchmaking) which tries to help making balanced games.

Comment: That's not the answer I'm looking for. I've played LoL and other games at a pretty high level (Plat I for LoL), but in this game, losing streaks AND winning streaks feel really "artificial"

Comment: what answer are you looking for? the part about MMR is the plain truth.... the tilting is an asumption

Comment: "hitten", like Hiten style? :P

Comment: corrected the typo ;-)